# Questions when using cnosdb's subscription function

Tags: cnosdb

In cnosdb, the subscription function supports the creation of a subscription from M to N. In this case, M has related data written, and a copy of the data will be synchronized to N. So when I create a subscription from N to M, a subscription ring will be formed at this time. When I write a data to M, will this data be cyclically synchronized between M and N? If they do, they can create an endless loop and inadvertently waste server resources